# Cannot find the file with my save data

Tags: ios

I have a Checklist app and I want to save the name of the items and if they are checked or not.
Xcode tells me that my saved file has to be here:

```
2012-11-11 20:24:42.726 Checklists[1459:c07] Documents directory /Users/astanciu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/F4A90B71-A8CF-4EF8-B628-508C8B50CAD0/Library/Documentation  
2012-11-11 20:24:42.728 Checklists[1459:c07] File path /Users/astanciu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/F4A90B71-A8CF-4EF8-B628-508C8B50CAD0/Library/Documentation/Checklists.plist
```

But in the Library folder I have only Caches and Preferences. Can't find anywhere the Checklists.plist file using Finder.

I am using Mountain Lion 10.8 and Xcode 4.5.2.

Code:

```
-(void)saveChecklistItems
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:items forKey:@"ChecklistItems"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self loadChecklistItems];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)loadChecklistItems
{
    NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        items = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"ChecklistItems"];
    }
    else
    {
        items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea what is the problem here ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code for determining `self dataFilePath`. It appears to reference `Library/Documentation` which is a non-standard directory.

Either you meant to use the `NSDocumentDirectory` constant instead of `NSDocumatationDirectory` in the code you have to determine the path, or you need to ensure that the directory exists before you try to write to it.

Comment: I was following a tutorial and just now realised that I wanted to use NSDocumentDIrectory. Thanks for poiting that out.